# Detecting when a call to a Windows URL protocol fails

Tags: c#, .net, process, protocols

I have a newly registered URL protocol that my application handles.  We'll call this `notify://`.  There are other applications in a suite that have calls like `Process.Start("notify://2125551234/");`  It might be the case the the actual application that is registered to handle these calls is not installed.  In such a case, I would want to detect that failure so I could maybe instead use the `callto://` protocol.

I started with:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "notify://2125551234/";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show(proc.ExitCode.ToString());
```

But this gets bizarre `Win32Exception The system cannot find the file specified.`  I get this error whether or not the protocol handler is installed or not.  How can I get this process started so I finally process the ExitCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `UseShellExecute` equal to `true` to start an application by using a URL.  When `UseShellExecute` is false `FileName` the Process object will only run an EXE directly.  The documentation for [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states that:

> When UseShellExecute is false, the FileName property must be a fully
>   qualified path to the executable.

Comment: Will this cause UAC issues?

Comment: Why would there be UAC issues?  Does one of these processes need administrative access?

Comment: @kmarks2 This causes UAC issue when calling process runs with elevated permissions. The URL does not get processed.